# DI in Value Conversions of .NET EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-core-3.0

I would like to use Value Conversions. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

When using it, I would like to add some config value. Sample usage is like this. (Unfortunately, this code does not run, but I want to write the code like this)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Rider>()
        .Property(e => e.Mount)
        .HasConversion(
            v => SomeFunction.Encrypt(v, IOptional<SomeConfig> config),
            v => SomeFunction.Decrypt(v, IOptional<SomeConfig> config));
}
```

More specifically, I would like to pass encrypt/decrypt key to the Converter functions. 
Is there any way to use DI config value in Value Conversions?

Comment: That would require spooky action at a distance. Why not create and pass in a `ValueConverter` (or else an `IEncryptor` with `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` methods) with no further configuration? You can then kick the creation and injection of that type up one level. The model builder should not be required to know that the value conversion needs configuration.

Comment: Where is `config` coming from?

Comment: I want to pass the encyrption key from Azure, KeyVault. As of now, in my application, I use Azure Function and I set the instance of IConfiguration with depedency injection (see the following link). Ideally, when I create the config instance , I would like to include the encryption key in the config instance and pass the key to my encryption/decryption method.[link](
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection)